# Omit rows containing specific column of NA

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I want to know how to omit `NA` values in a data frame, but only in some columns I am interested in.

For example,

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(0, 10, NA), z=c(NA, 33, 22))
```

but I only want to omit the data where `y` is `NA`, therefore the result should be

```
  x  y  z
1 1  0 NA
2 2 10 33
```

`na.omit` seems delete all rows contain any `NA`.

Can somebody help me out of this simple question?

But if now I change the question like:

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3,NA), y = c(1,0, 10, NA), z=c(43,NA, 33, NA))
```

If I want to omit only `x=na` or `z=na`, where can I put the `|` in function?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You could use the `complete.cases` function and put it into a function thusly:

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(0, 10, NA), z=c(NA, 33, 22))

completeFun <- function(data, desiredCols) {
  completeVec <- complete.cases(data[, desiredCols])
  return(data[completeVec, ])
}

completeFun(DF, "y")
#   x  y  z
# 1 1  0 NA
# 2 2 10 33

completeFun(DF, c("y", "z"))
#   x  y  z
# 2 2 10 33
```

**EDIT:** *Only return rows with no `NA`s*

If you want to eliminate all rows with at least one `NA` in any column, just use the `complete.cases` function straight up:

```
DF[complete.cases(DF), ]
#   x  y  z
# 2 2 10 33
```

Or if `completeFun` is already ingrained in your workflow ;)

```
completeFun(DF, names(DF))
```

Comment: Can you make your approach greedy? Take all columns that do not have NAs at all.

Comment: You mean just return *rows* with no `NA`s? Like `completeFun(DF, names(DF))`?

Comment: Correct! Please, consider adding it to your answer because it is a common need here. - - I think mnel's answer cannot be expanded as yours. Your function approach is great!

Comment: Done! Thx for the tip @LéoLéopoldHertz준영

Comment: If you are viewing this past 2020 do yourself a favor and look at the more recent answers given below, for example the approach outlined by @amrrs below using `drop_na()` from `tidyr` does the same thing but is in my opinion a better solution today.

Answer (score 244):

Use `is.na`

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(0, 10, NA), z=c(NA, 33, 22))
DF[!is.na(DF$y),]
```

Comment: How do you apply this approach greedily on all columns in the data set? If any of the column value is NA skip. So your data set output is the second column only.

Comment: Use `na.omit` to greedily remove all rows with NA in any column `na.omit(DF)`

Answer (score 109):

Hadley's `tidyr` just got this amazing function `drop_na`

```
library(tidyr)
DF %>% drop_na(y)
  x  y  z
1 1  0 NA
2 2 10 33
```

Comment: This method also allows you to specify more than one column (for dropping NA values). For instance, one could use DF %>% drop_na(y,z) to remove NA values in both columns, y, and z.

Comment: @SolingerStuebchen can you pass a list for the columns to drop?

Comment: @queste yes, that is possible. You can do the following to drop NA values in multiple columns. First, define a list of column to be checked: drop_list <- c("y","z"). Second, you call DF%>% drop_na(drop_list).

Answer (score 36):

Use 'subset'

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(0, 10, NA), z=c(NA, 33, 22))
subset(DF, !is.na(y))
```

Answer (score 17):

It is possible to use `na.omit` for `data.table`:

```
na.omit(data, cols = c("x", "z"))
```

Comment: the `cols=` argument is available in the `data.table::na.omit` library. Not the base `stats::na.omit`.

Answer (score 7):

Omit row if either of two specific columns contain `<NA>`.

```
DF[!is.na(DF$x)&!is.na(DF$z),]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
cc=is.na(DF$y)
m=which(cc==c("TRUE"))
DF=DF[-m,]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try this:

```
DF %>% t %>% na.omit %>% t
```

It transposes the data frame and omits null rows which were 'columns' before transposition and then you transpose it back.

Comment: Please explain a bit what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

To update, a `tidyverse` approach with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

your_data_frame %>% 
  filter(!is.na(region_column))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a custom function with `complete.cases` to remove the rows with NA in a certain column. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
DF <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(0, 10, NA), z=c(NA, 33, 22))
DF
#>   x  y  z
#> 1 1  0 NA
#> 2 2 10 33
#> 3 3 NA 22
DF[complete.cases(DF$y),]
#>   x  y  z
#> 1 1  0 NA
#> 2 2 10 33
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see, it removed the row with NA in certain column.