# Remove entire Row if Column == NA in R

Tags: r, na

Trying to remove this row and cannot get it. I have tried the multiple Q&A's on SO already and nothing seems to work. Tried using the `sjmisc` library as someone suggested but it is still there. Here is what I have tried below and a snip of the `df`.

**EDIT:**

Here is a DataFrame below to test. Removed a Pic of the dataframe which was incorrect and not proper policy.

```
df<-data.frame(name=c('CAREY.PRICE',NA,'JOHN.SMITH'),GA=c(3,2,2),SV=c(2,2,NA),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Which will return:

```
name       |  GA  | SV
CAREY.PRICE|  3   | 2
NA         |  2   | 2
John.Smith |  2   | NA
```

The issue with the below response:

```
df = df[complete.cases(df),]
```

It answers the question above technically, If a Column in any row has NA, remove it. I should have clarified that I would have like it to be a column of my choice which would have been the `NA` in `df$name`.

What this will do is remove `NA` and `John.Smith`. Which has caused an issue with my script and the lack of `name`(players) in my DF.

I also had `na.omit()` in my script and it removed `NA` and John.Smith as well.
There are 40 variables in my DF and to write out each possible one that may or may not have an NA in it would be too much. My temporary solution is to change all NA's to 0:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

RETURNS:

```
name       |  GA  | SV
CAREY.PRICE|  3   | 2
0          |  2   | 2
John.Smith |  2   | 0
```

Then remove any `df$name` that is 0:

```
df<-df[!(df$name==0),]
```

What I was looking for:

```
name       |  GA  | SV
CAREY.PRICE|  3   | 2
John.Smith |  2   | 0
```

Comment: have you tried `na.omit()`?

Comment: yes, I have tried

Comment: Fixed the question above @Tjebo. Let me know if there is quicker solution. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254524/omit-rows-containing-specific-column-of-na.  I am using this custom made function `complete_fun` in those cases. I have it in my own personal utility package. Or, as the most upvoted answer to this question suggests or per my comment below - use `df[!is.na(df$name),]`

Comment: I will also flag this as a duplicate - really don't want to be mean. This will just help to direct people to the other question which had already very good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to filter our rows with an NA in the `name` field:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(!is.na(name))

#>          name GA SV
#> 1 CAREY.PRICE  3  2
#> 2  JOHN.SMITH  2 NA
```

Comment: Nice, I would then apply the na convert to 0 for other variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`complete. cases` finds the rows that don't have any NA's.

Hence, the answer to your question is:

```
df = df[complete.cases(df),]
```

Comment: it changes the output to a `factor` and not `dataframe`

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much. Been struggling with this for awhile now.

Comment: @MichaelTJohnson is a `factor` output acceptable?

Comment: I think `df[!is.na(df),]` might bring the same result - better sample data by the OP would help. I don't understand why `na.omit` would not yield the desired effect though.

Comment: @Salman, I am not sure the difference to be honest. My script was successful. I will have to look up what it is.

Comment: Found an error with this and I will discuss this above.